# Vuex getter returning null

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

Here's my store.js

```
const state = {
id: null,
trainingTypeName: null,
trainingTypes: [],
trainingType: null

};
```

My mutation

```
const mutations = {

'GET_TRAINING_TYPES' (state,trainingtypes){
    state.trainingTypes = trainingtypes
},
storeTraining(state,trainingType){
    state.trainingType = trainingType
}

};
```

My Action

```
const actions = {
getTrainingTypes({ commit }){
    axios.get('/select')
        .then(response => {

            const data = response.data
            const trainingTypes = []
            for(let key in data){
                const trainingType = data[key]
                trainingType.id = key
                trainingTypes.push(trainingType)

            }

            commit('storeTraining',trainingTypes[0])

        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
};
```

My Getters

```
const getters = {
trainings(state){
    return state.trainingType
}
};
```

The below image is what I'm getting on my api.
[my api return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWUrx.png)

And in my component

```
<template>      
      <p>Training Type Name: {{ training }}</p>
</template>

<script>

    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        created(){
            this.$store.dispatch('getTrainingTypes')
        },
        computed: {
            training(){
                return this.$store.getters.trainings.trainingTypeName
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

I'm getting an error "TypeError: this.$store.getters.trainings is null" though it has a data. Any advise where is my mistake here?

Comment: The server call is asynchronous. It won't complete until after the component has rendered. So when it first renders the value will still be `null`.

Comment: yes that’s correct but you can see that in my created hook, i’m sending a get request and you can see in the image the return of the api. by the way, i have already fixed this. my mistake was i’m importing the incorrect store.js